# Pandas - Create a column (col C) with values from another (col A) if a condition in another column (col B) is observed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a DataFrame as we can see in Table A with two columns. The values on column A are int starting on 1. The values in column B are binary.

I need to create column C (Table B) in which:
 if the values on column B are 1, then get the values on column A for that respective row, 
 else if the value on columns B is 0 then column C will be 0 for that respective row.

Example
Table A:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 6 |  1|
| 10|  0|
| 50|  0|
|100|  1|
| 5 |  1|
| 2 |  0|
+---+---+
```

Table B:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| 6 |  1| 6 |
| 10|  0| 0 |
| 50|  0| 0 |
|100|  1|100|
| 5 |  1| 5 |
| 2 |  0| 0 |
+---+---+---|
```

code:

```
# create df
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': [6,10,50,100,5,2], 'B': [1,0,0,1,1,0]}
dfA = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
dfA
```

Could anyone help me, please? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the nice minimal working example!

I would solve it like this:

```
dfA['C'] = dfA['A']          # copy A to C
dfA['C'][dfA['B'] == 0] = 0  # set all positions in C where B is 0 to 0
```

The resulting `dfA`:

```
     A  B    C
0    6  1    6
1   10  0    0
2   50  0    0
3  100  1  100
4    5  1    5
5    2  0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

In a [numpy where clause](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) the first argument is the condition the next one is the "then" section then the "else" is list

```
import numpy as np
df['C'] = np.where(df['B']==1, df['B'], 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If column `B` is 0 or 1 you can just multiple column A and B using [`prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) on `axis=1`

```
dfA['C'] = dfA.prod(axis=1)
#dfA['C'] = dfA[['A','B']].prod(axis=1) if you have more columns
print(dfA)
```

---

```
     A  B    C
0    6  1    6
1   10  0    0
2   50  0    0
3  100  1  100
4    5  1    5
5    2  0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dfA['C']=0
dfA.loc[dfA['B']==1, 'C'] = dfA['A']
dfA
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value